# Postgresql trigger changes all column values after activating

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I created a "for each statement" trigger and a trigger function that add tax to the price. After each "insert" every value in a column "price" increments by my tax, but i need to add a tax only to incoming "insert price". I know that the "for each row" will solve it, but still can I solve this issue through "for each statement"? DB Postgres

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(50),
    producer varchar(50),
    count integer DEFAULT 0,
    price integer
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tax()
    returns TRIGGER AS
$$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE products
        SET price = price * 1.2;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER tax_trigger
    AFTER INSERT
    ON products
    FOR EACH STATEMENT
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE tax();

INSERT INTO products (name, producer, count, price) VALUES ('product_3', 'producer_3', 8, 115);
INSERT INTO products (name, producer, count, price) VALUES ('product_1', 'producer_1', 3, 50);
```

Here after first insert product_3 price is 115(is not changed), but after second insert i have product_1 is 50(is not changed) and product_3 price is 138(changed???).

Comment: A statement level trigger **cannot** refer to individual rows that have been professed, since the pseudo rows Old and New do not exist. As a consequence your trigger update every existing row in the table on every statement. So product_3 gets price = 115 when the row is processed. They gets updated to 138 when the trigger fires. Your second statement then sets the price of product_1 to 50.  Then your trigger fires again (as this is a new statement)  and since there is **NO where condition it updates every row**.  Further, as it stands, any subsequent insert will update every row again.

Comment: @Belayer Thanks, but even if i use a where clause, then trigger will update every row that matches where clause. How to update only incoming price, but not any existing prices? Is it possible through statement level? I still don't understand why in same case "for each row" don't change values that already exists in a table, but "for each statement" do. In my task i must do this trigger through "for each statement".

Comment: Is it possible through statement level? **NO**. A row level trigger has access to the individual roe being processed, a statement level does not, it can only access the entire table (assuming referencing only the table it fired upon). Moreover you do not use an Update statement. You access the column(s) directly through the pseudo row New.  In the case the trigger consists on 1 statement: `new.price = new.price * 1.2`.   However you probably want to change the data type of `price`, as an integer it will be truncated/rounded.